Gab es jemals vokative Nomen- oder wenigstesn Namensformen im Deutschen?
Ich habe vor einiger Zeit in Goethe's Faust eine vokative oder wenigestens vokativ klingende Namensform gefunden:

Nun, Fauste, träume fort, bis wir uns wiedersehn.

Ist das einfach künstlerische Freiheit, oder vielleicht eine damals noch benutzte aber unübliche Namensform?
Wikipedia deutet auf keine deutschen Vokativformen hin, außer einem vorgesetzten “o”... Allerdings kommt mir das eher als eine Interjektion vor (ver­gleichs­wei­se “ach”) als als eine Vokativform.
Vor allem ist das in dem angegebenen Beispiel auffällig — “Nun, o Faust, [...]” würde auf einem gewissen Maß an Hochachtung hindeuten.
Jedenfalls wundere ich mich:

Ob es je eine Vokativform im Deutschen gab
Wenn ja, wann diese außer Gebrauch geraten ist.

Auch habe ich mich gewundert ob verschiedene Namensvarianten — vor allem altertümlicherer Namen — nicht vielleicht solcher früheren Vokativformen entspringen, z.B. Krimhild/e, Si(e)glind/e, Brunhild/e, Hildegund/e, Erdmut/e, Uta/Ute, Inga/Inge, Ottilia/Ottilie usw.

Zunächst war eine unbetonte Silbe hier nötig, weil sonst der Reim nicht aufgegangen wäre. Aus demselben Grunde auch "So recht, ihr luft'gen zarten Jungen!" und nicht "luftigen". Daß Goethe gerade "Fauste" wählt, könnte schon damit zu tun haben, daß "Faustus" ja als lateinisches Substantiv der o-Deklination interpretiert werden kann, zu dem dann der Vokativ "-e" passen würde. Aber das ist mMn Spekulation. Das fällt eher unter "verstechnische Freiheit" als "deutscher Sprachgebrauch".

Tatsache ist, daß der unmittelbare Vorgänger des Deutschen in der Entwicklungsreihe der (indo-)germanischen Sprachen, Gotisch, noch einen Vokativ hatte.

Keine Ahnung, ob das Reste von Vokativ sind, aber ich kann mich erinnern, dass wir Bekannte hatten, die aus Siebenbürgen stammten - Die Frau sprach ihren Mann, der Arthur hieß, immer mit "Arthure" an.

@bakunin Die "Latein-Theorie" ist plausibel und einer offiziellen Antwort wert.

@tofro die Siebenbürgische form Arthure könnte eine Leihform des rumänischen Vokativs sein, oder auch nur mit dieser konvergieren. Wäre jedenfalls einer Erwähnung in der Antwort wert, da sie dieselbe Endung benutzt wie in meinem Beispiel, und wie in der von @ bakunin erwähnten lateinischen Deklination.

Das war auch ein bißchen meine Vermutung: Vielleicht hat das Siebenbürger Deutsch ein bißchen Vokativ aus dem Rumänischen übernommen? Außer meiner Erinnerung habe ich allerdings keinen Beleg dafür.

@TheChymera Der rumänische Vokativ dürfte ein Erbstück aus dem Lateinischen sein.

In Faust Teil 2 findet sich an zwei Stellen die lateinische Form "Faustus".

Der unmittelbare (zeitliche) Vorläufer des Deutschen in den germanischen Sprachen (und die erste germanische Sprache die schriftlich belegt ist) ist Gotisch. Gotisch war um das 6. Jahrhundert, also die Zeit der Formierung des Deutschen als eigene Sprache, eine lingua franca in Europa und hatte nicht nur einen Vokativ, sondern auch großen Einfluß auf die Entwicklung der deutschen Sprache. Die nächsten Verwandten des Gotischen, Litauisch und Lettisch, haben diesen Vokativ erhalten (Litauisch sogar ausgebaut).
Ob die ältesten Stufen des (althoch-)Deutschen noch einen Vokativ hatten oder ob der bei der "Erfindung" der Sprache verlorenging, ist fraglich. Zumindest die übrigen germanischen Sprachen haben im Gegensatz zu Gotisch keinen Vokativ. Gerade aber bei der Formierung des Deutschen (aus Altbairisch, Langobardisch, ...) ist die Beleglage reichlich dünn. Bei Otfried jedenfalls (9. Jahrhundert) gibt es keinen vom Nominativ zu unterscheidenden Vokativ mehr.
Es gibt bei manchen Germanisten die - nicht allgemein akzeptierte - Idee, im Deutschen einen Vokativ zu postulieren, der allerdings formgleich mit dem Nominativ ist. Die Sinnhaftigkeit eines solchen Postulats erschließt sich mir allerdings nicht.
Um auf das Zitat zurückzukommen:
Goethe brauchte einfach eine weitere unbetonte Silbe um den Vers zu füllen und vermutlich - für Details müßte man ihn selber fragen - lag es nahe, den Faustus, der ja an ein lateinisches Maskulinum der o-Deklination erinnert, auch zu einem lateinischen Vokativ zu deklinieren. Der würde nämlich in der Tat Fauste lauten.

Zitat: »Der unmittelbare (zeitliche) Vorläufer des Deutschen in den germanischen Sprachen [...] ist Gotisch« Das ist falsch!!! Gotisch war eine Ost-Germanische Sprache. Deutsch ist hingegen eine West-Germanische Sprache, also eine Schwester oder Nichte des Gotischen, aber keinesfalls eine direkte Nachfahrin. Es ist richtig, dass Gotisch die erste germanische Sprache mit einer Schrift war, aber daraus ist eben nicht Deutsch entstanden. (Gotisch ist die einzige bekannte Ostgermanische Sprache und ist ohne Nachfolgersprache ausgestorben.)

@HubertSchölnast: Willst Du behaupten, daß Gotisch nicht zeitlich vor Deutsch kam? Oder verstehst Du den Unterschied zwischen zeitlich (wie ich schrieb) und direkt (wie Du schriebst) nicht, sodaß es für Dich das Gleiche ist? Nebenbei gesagt, ist die Antinomie von "Vorläufer" nicht "Nachfahr" - Isaac Newton ist zwar ein Vorläufer von Albert Einstein, aber Einstein nicht dessen Nachfahr. "Direkt" geht also ins Leere, "Nachfahr" ebenso.

Zitat: »Die direkten Abkömmlinge des Gotischen, Litauisch und Lettisch, [...]« Das ist gleich doppelt falsch!!! 1.: Gotisch hat genau gar keine Nachfolgersprachen. Es ist als einzige bekannte ostgermanische Sprache einfach ausgestorben. Die letzten gotisch sprechenden Manschen starben vermutlich im 18. Jahrhundert, vermutlich auf der Krim. 2.: Die baltischen Sprachen sind keine germanischen Sprachen. Sie sind mit den slawischen Sprachen deutlich enger verwandt als mit den germanischen Sprachen, obwohl sie selbst auch keine slawischen Sprachen sind. Die baltischen ...

... Sprachen sind ein eigenständiger Zweig innerhalb des großen Stammbaums der indogermanischen Sprachen.

@HubertSchölnast: Davon abgesehen: wann immer Linguisten sich an der Entwicklung der deutschen Sprache abarbeiten, wird Althochdeutsch als älteste deutsche Sprachstufe mit dem Gotischen verglichen, weshalb es methodologisch sinnvoll erscheint, ebendiesen Vergleich anzustellen. Vielen Dank für die Aufklärung, daß die Linguisten alle Äpfel mit Birnen vergleichen.

Im Gotischen ist der Vokativ identisch mit dem Nominativ oder dem Akkusativ.

@bakunin danke für die Antwort. Die Einsicht, dass Fauste die lateinische Vokativform für Faustus ist, finde ich sehr relevant, weil sie eine Erklärung dafür bietet wieso unter allen anderen Vokalen gerade “e” gewählt wurde.

Kurze Antworten:

Gab es den Vokativ als eigenständigen grammatischen Fall in einer Sprachstufe des Deutschen?
Nein

Wann ist der Vokativ als eigenständiger grammatischer Fall in der Linie der direkten Vorgängersprachen des Deutschen außer Gebrauch geraten?
Vermutlich im ersten Jahrtausend vor Christus, also rund 750 bis 1750 Jahre bevor es eine deutsche Sprache gab.

Woher kommt das e am Ende von Fauste im Satz »Nun, Fauste, träume fort, bis wir uns wiedersehn«?
Das kommt daher, dass Goethe den Rhythmus des Versmaßes in dem Gedicht erhalten wollte, und er am Ende von »Faust« noch eine unbetonte Silbe brauchte.

Der Herr der Ratten und der Mäuse,
Der Fliegen, Frösche, Wanzen, Läuse,
Befiehlt dir dich hervor zu wagen
Und diese Schwelle zu benagen,
So wie er sie mit Oel betupft –
Da kommst du schon hervorgehupft!
Nur frisch ans Werk! Die Spitze, die mich bannte,
Sie sitzt ganz vornen an der Kante.
Noch einen Biß, so ist’s geschehn. –
Nun Fauste träume fort, bis wir uns wiedersehn.



Ergänzung:
Der Vokativ existiert nach wie vor im Deutschen, jedoch nicht als grammatischer Fall sondern als Stilfigur. Hier sind Beispiele:

Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren
Liebe Sabine
O Tannenbaum


Lange Antwort
Den Vokativ gab es als eigenständigen Kasus sehr wahrscheinlich in der indogermanischen Ursprache, die der Vorläufer der europäischen und indoiranischen Sprachen ist. Deutsch ist eine dieser Nachfolgesprachen der indogermanischen Sprachen, daher ist nur die Frage zu klären, ob der Zeitpunkt, ab dem man einer Sprache den Namen »Deutsch« gibt, zeitlich vor oder nach dem Verschwinden des Vokativ als Kasus liegt.
Wenn man von der Gegenwart in die Vergangenheit geht, begegnet man diesen Sprachstufen:

Neuhochdeutsch seit ca. 1650
Frühneuhochdeutsch ca. 1350 - 1650
Mittelhochdeutsch ca. 1050 - 1350
Althochdeutsch ca. 750 - 1050
Voralthochdeutsche Dialekte vor ca. 750

Die voralthochdeutschen Dialekte sind die Dialekte der Bajuwaren, Alemannen, Thüringer, Franken, Langobarden, usw., also jener Völker, die allesamt eine Form des Westgermanischen gesprochen haben, und aus deren Vereinigung die deutsche Sprache entstanden ist. Nachdem das Wort »deutsch« (damalige Form: »diutisc«, Bedeutung: zum Volk gehörend, das Volk betreffend) erst nach 750 in dieser Bedeutung verwendet wurde, zählen die voralthochdeutsche Dialekte nicht zu den Sprachstufen der deutschen Sprache, sondern sind in ihrer Gesamtheit eben eine nicht-deutsche Vorläufersprache des Deutschen.
Den Übergang von dieser Vorläufersprache zum Althochdeutschen kennzeichnet aber nicht das Auftauchen eines Wortes, das im modernen Deutsch zu »deutsch« geworden ist, sondern die zweite Lautverschiebung. Das war ein Prozess, der auch nicht über Nacht passierte, sondern rund 150 Jahre dauerte, und bei dem vor allem Konsonanten durch andere Konsonanten ersetzt wurden. Eine Veränderung im Kasus-System ging damit nicht einher. Schon die voralthochdeutschen Dialekte verwendeten dieselben vier grammatischen Fälle, die auch noch im modernen Deutsch existieren: Nominativ, Genitiv, Dativ und Akkusativ. Die Details des Gebrauchs dieser vier Fälle wiesen zwischen den verschiedenen Dialekten durchaus Unterschiede auf, aber es waren dieselben vier Fälle, und der Vokativ war da nicht darunter.
Die voralthochdeutschen Dialekte gehörten zum westlichen Zweig der urgermanischen Sprache. (Aus dem östlichen Zweig entstand Gotisch, das aber keine lebende Sprache mehr ist, und aus dem nördlichen Zweig entstanden die nordgermanischen Sprache, zu denen z.B. Dänisch und Schwedisch gehören).
Der Vorläufer der urgermanischen Sprache ist die prä-germanische Sprache. Diese Sprachstufe ist nicht nur nicht deutsch, sie zählt auch nicht zu den germanischen Sprachen. Die Entstehung der urgermanischen Sprache aus der prä-germanische Sprache ist die erste (germanische) Lautverschiebung, die vermutlich mehr als 500 Jahre lang gedauert hat und vermutlich die Zeit von ca. 500 v. Chr. bis ca. zur Zeitenwende in Anspruch nahm. Auch dieser Übergang manifestiert sich nicht an einem Wechsel des Kasussystems, was niucht bedeutet, dass kein Wechsel dieses Systems stattfand. Das ging allerdings sehr, sehr langsam vonstatten
In der prä-germanische Sprache gab es noch einen Vokativ, der wurde jedoch schon zur Zeit der ersten Lautverschiebung nur noch wenig verwendet. Der Vokativ brauchte vermutlich fast ein ganzes Jahrtausend, um sich in den Vorläuferstufen der deutschen Sprache von einem echten grammatischen Fall (mit eigener Kasus-Endung beim Substantiv) zu einer rhetorischen Form (ohne Markierung am Substantiv) zu wandeln, und das geschah lange Zeit bevor man das, was die Menschen damals sprachen, »Deutsch« nennen konnte. In anderen, nicht-germanischen Sprachen, die zeitgleich in Europa existierten, und die ebenfalls aus der indoeuropäischen Ursprache hervorgingen, konnte sich der Vokativ jedoch bis heute halten (viele slawische und baltische Sprachen).

Daß der "Vokativ im ersten Jahrtausend vor Christus außer Gebrauch" geraten wäre, ist definitv falsch: sowohl Latein (das wurde bis ins 5. Jhdt. u.Z. als lebende Sprache gesprochen) hatte einen markierten Vokativ, Huberte, und auch das Koine, also das klassische Griechisch, immerhin die Sprache des Oströmischen Imperiums ("Βασιλεία τῶν Ῥωμαίων") kennt einen Vokativ - und dazu die Vokativpartikel "ω", aus der das deutsche "O [Gott oder dgl.]" hervorgeht.

@bakunin: Du hast recht, da war schlampig formuliert. Ich habe es korrigiert.

@HubertSchölnast danke für die ausführliche Antwort. Die Kurzantwort (3) könnte vielleicht darum ergänzt werden wieso gerade “e” gewählt wurde. Eine andere Antwort bietet eine Erklärung an, mir würden jedenfalls andere Vokale skuriller vorkommen — Fausti fällt raus weil eindeutig diminutiv, aber... Faustu... Fausto... Fausta? Fauste klingt irgendwie schon viel intuitiver als Aufruf.

Das Deutsche hat wahrscheinlich nie einen Vokativ gekannt.
Wenn noch Reste übrig sind, dann sind sie mikroskopisch und finden sich am ehesten noch in Kommata:
"Nun, Herr Scholz, was machen Sie jetzt?"
"Hans, gib' mir mal die Milch"
"Herr Professor, können Sie das nochmal erklären"
Die jeweils durch Kommata abgetrennten Anreden würden z.B. im Lateinischen (das auch nur noch einen rudimentären Vokativ hat) im Vokativ stehen. Im Deutschen stellt man eben die Kommata. Die Anreden stehen im Nominativ, sind aber keine "ordentlichen" Satzglieder (kein Subjekt, Objekt,...).
Das Deutsche "verziert" solche Anreden auch gerne mit Personalpronomen oder Partikeln und markiert damit die Anreden:
"So, mein Freund, jetzt gehen wir aus"
"O Gott, was ist nur passiert?"
"So, ihr Richter, wie urteilt ihr jetzt?"

Es gibt einen Unterschied zwischen »Oh Gott« und »O Gott«. Letzteres (O ohne h) kennzeichnet eine Anrede, also einen stilistischen Vokativ (»O Gott, vergib mir«). Wenn das »Oh« mit einem »h« daherkommt, ist es eine Interjektion des Erstaunens, also keine Anrede und daher auch kein Vokativ.
